# subprocess.Popen sometimes return non zero exit code

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, exit-code

My code calls a number of processes running a different python script using subprocess.Popen functions and waits for all of them to finish running. 
**Sometimes** (Not all of the runs, even with identical params) one or more of the processes are not running (the first thing in the called code is the creation of a log file which is not created in those cases).

```
for fname1 in input_files_1:
    cmd_list = create_batch_cmd(fname1)
    print (' '.join(cmd_list))
    p_list.append(Popen(' '.join(cmd_list), shell=True))
    logging.info("started process for %s" % fname1)

logging.info("waiting for processes")
ps_status = []
while True:
    ps_status = [p.poll() for p in p_list]
    if all([x is not None for x in ps_status]):
        break
logging.info("all processes finished")
print ps_status
```

ps_status usually is a list of zeros.
In a run of 12 processes when 3 failed, ps_status was:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

What could cause this? and how can I investigate?
Thanks

Comment: You know you can write `ps_status = [p.wait() for p in p_list]` instead of the whole while-construct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your processes number 3,8,10 fail , it is not a python problem since all others seems to be working fine. and maybe you should do p.wait() instead of poll()

Comment: Thanks, probably the problem is in the server handling my requests